# Why does my SplashScreen Not show a Label (Text)

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I have a `WinForm` called `SpalshScreen.cs` with a simple label with the `Text` property is set to "Data Loading...". The label is centered in the Form. I also have a public method called `DoClose()` method defined.

My `MainForm.Form_Load` method contains:

```
Hide();
SplashScreen form = new SplashScreen();
form.Show();

// Simulate Doing Database Table Load(s)
Thread.Sleep(5000);

form.DoClose();
Show();
```

However when I run, my Splash does appear but, where the Label Text is suppose to be it only shows a Light Colored Box.

If I change `form.Show();` to `form.ShowDialog();` the text appears correctly but the main loop pauses until I close the Splash Window.

Comment: Do your database load in a non-UI thread, rather than in the UI thread.

Comment: No they all load in the UI thread.

Comment: It wasn't a question, but an advice.

Comment: @Randy Yes.  That's why your code isn't working.  Don't do that.

Comment: O.K. Warning This is going to be a stupid question on my part, do you mean doing a context.Table.LoadAsync(); ?

Comment: @Randy That's one way of not blocking the UI thread, yes.

Comment: Never do database work in your UI thread. You need to use async or a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of trial and error... The trick is to Not block the UI Thread as @Servy said.

The Form_Load method needed to change to:

```
Hide();
Splash.Show();

// Everything after this line must be Non UI Thread Blocking
Task task = new Task(LoadDataAsync);
task.Start();
task.Wait();

Splash.DoClose();
Show();
```

And I created a LoadDataAsync Method to take care of everything else:

```
    private async void LoadDataAsync()
    {
        await Context.Employees.LoadAsync();
        await Context.Customers.LoadAsync();

        // The Invoke/Action Wrapper Keeps Modification of UI Elements from
        // complaining about what thread they are on.
        if (EmployeeDataGridView.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action act = () => EmployeeBindingSource.DataSource = Context.Employees.Local.ToBindingList();
            EmployeeDataGridView.Invoke(act);
        }

        if (CustomerComboBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = GetCustomerList();
                CustomerComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
            };
            CustomerComboBox.Invoke(act);
        }
    }
```

I also set any of the private fields and private methods I was using to static.

Answer (score 0):

Use timer inside your splashscreen form instead of thread.sleep ( for example close splash screen after 5 seconds), and set closed event of it.

```
var form = new SplashScreen();
form.Closed += (s,e)=>{
    Show();
}
form.Show();
```